# Livewire - Nesting components - inline javascript not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

#### Description

I have a "parent-child" situation, which I am trying to use Livewire for.  My issue is that any inline Javascript written on the child component is not working.

#### Exact steps to reproduce

Consider the two components `Master` and `Child`:

```html
<!-- master.blade.php -->
<div>
    <a wire:click="$set('task', true)">Open Task</a>
    @if($task)
        <livewire:test.child :task="$task"></livewire:test.child>
    @endif
</div>
```

```php
//Master.php
class Master extends Component
{
    public $task;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test.master');
    }
}
```

In the above master component, whenever I click on "Open Task", the `$task` variable will be set to true. This will make the `child` component render. The child component looks like this:

```html
<!-- child.blade.php -->
<div class="p-4">
    The task is set.<br />
    <a onclick="showName('Test Task')">Show task</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showName(name){
               alert("Task name is: " + name);
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

```php
//Child.php
class Child extends Component
{
    public $task;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test.child');
    }
}
```

When clicking on `Show Task` in the child, I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: showName is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (:2:1)

Further, on the child component, I would like to know when Livewire has finished loading on that specific component, thus adding the below. (As documented [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/inline-scripts))

```js
//child.blade.php
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () { 
    console.log("Livewire finished loading in child.")
});
```

The the above is never fired off either.

**Context**

- Alpine version: 2.7.3
- Livewire version: 2.3.6
- Laravel version: 8.12
- Browser: Chrome

Answer (score 0):

on child component you must have a mount function that must have a parameter named $task . Try this:

```
class Child extends Component
{
    public $task;

    public function mount($task){
        $this->task  = $task
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test.child');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons livewire is not pushing the scripts from child component to app.blade but you can push the script from the parent to the app. If you want to load js for the child component you can use livewire:update inside the parent and when a new livewire component is loaded or livewire sends a request it will load the js for you.

Your code should look like this now:

```
<!-- master.blade.php -->
<div>
    <a wire:click="$set('task', true)">Open Task</a>
    @if($task)
        <livewire:test.child :task="$task"></livewire:test.child>
    @endif
</div>

@push('scripts')
<script>
/* This will be loaded when livewire update or load a new component inside master.blade.php */
 document.addEventListener('livewire:update', function () {
        // Your JS for child component here.
 })
</script>
@endpush
```

Don't forget to include `@stack('scripts')` inside your app.blade.php